# Trying to add Tomcat v7 to eclipse, but cannot find it in "Define a New Server" window

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, runtime

I'm trying to create a dynamic web project in eclipse, but my version of Apache Tomcat is v7 and the list of abvailable tomcat servers when I try to define the new server are from v3.2 to v6.0, there is nothing higher.

I tried to click "Download additional server adapters" but could not find any updated versions of tomcat there.  I have a tomcat server working on my machine, but I wanted to link it with Eclipse to make development easier.

I've also tried going to Window -> Preferences -> Server Tab -> Installed Runtimes tab and clicking search, then selecting my tomcat installation folder.  It doesn't add anything and doesn't give any error.

Any ideas of how to do this?  I think the version difference may be the reason I can't get my eclipse projects to compile directly to the tomcat server and I can't figure out how to add it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using a version of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers equal to or greater than 3.6 (Helios). Other builds and earlier versions do not have the adapter for Tomcat 7. Make sure you are running the latest version of the web tools as well. Also try letting eclipse search for it under server->runtime environment. It may detect it for you, if you are running a new enough version of EE.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded Indigo and can add the server fine now.  I feel like the naming conventions Eclipse is switching between are kind of confusing to early adopters.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Eclipse 3.7 aka Indigo.
Also, make sure you download the EE version as you'll have everything you need to build web services.

Comment: Not entirely true, the support is already in Eclipse 3.6 (Helios).

Comment: You are right but i think this is not so important to solve the question... Don't you think so?

Answer (score 1):

@Manjush

Thanks for the pointer. Editing in Windows preferences is a good thought. For me, it dint allow to add because I had given a wrong path of the server. I am using Eclipse Kepler.

```
Windows->Preferences->Servers-->Runtime Environments-->Add
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows->Preferences->Servers->Installed Runtimes and add (point 
to) an installed Tomcat 7 installation on your system.