# How to add new version of Apache Tomcat to configure new server?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, editor

I am following [Jaime's Ideas](http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.in/2012/02/adding-tomcat-application-server-to.html) to add new Tomcat server version 7 for configuring new server.

[image]

But when configuring new server, recently added Tomcat server version 7 is not listed.

Please help me, to list recently added tomcat server version to configure new server.

**Edit:**

I'm new to this Eclipse editor. Earlier, It was working. When I am trying to set up new project in my eclipse editor, I have removed previously configured server and when I am trying to configure again I am getting this problem.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think trying a new version of eclipse will be good

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894926/trying-to-add-tomcat-v7-to-eclipse-but-cannot-find-it-in-define-a-new-server

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Juno service release 1

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Server Tab -> Installed Runtimes` tab and click `search`, then select tomcat installation folder.